# run adhoc wait_for with delegate_to

Tags: ansible

my Makefile has the following steps

```
   create:
       do create stuff
       # extra ansible adhoc command to wait for ssh

   setup:
       do other stuff
```

I'd like to add a step after `do create stuff` that waits until all hosts have their ssh port accesible, but i dont want to have to commit an extra playbook that just does this:

```
  - hosts: all
    tasks:
      - name: wait for ssh port
        wait_for:
          host: '{{ ansible_ssh_host }}'
          port: 22
          timeout: 300
        delegate_to: localhost
```

I've tried using an adhoc command that will run the command above but with local action

```
ansible all -i inventory -m local_action -a 'wait_for port=22 timeout=300'
```

but thats not correct cause

```
ERROR! this task 'local_action' has extra params, which is only allowed in the following modules: command, win_command, shell, win_shell, script, include, include_vars, add_host, group_by, set_fact, raw, meta
```

Comment: ansible localhost -m wait_for -a 'host=localhost port=22 timeout=300'

Comment: Could you explain what you want to achieve? It doesn't make much sense. When you execute it in a playbook, multiple tasks will wait individually for each host before proceeding with other tasks for its particular host. When you execute it in ad-hoc mode you have only one thread, so how do you want to run it against multiple targets?

Comment: i've updated the question to make it more clear on what im trying to do

Comment: Try this : ansible all -m wait_for -a 'host={{ansible_ssh_host}} port=22 timeout=30'

Comment: but that will execute the command on the server i need to check if its alive. And it will fail with `SSH Error`

Comment: @user2599522,  So you want to check whether all the target servers are pingable or not ?

Comment: Not pingable. Ssh-able.

Answer (score 1):

> my Makefile has the following steps
>
> ```
> create:
>    do create stuff
>    # extra ansible adhoc command to wait for ssh
> ```

From comments:

> - So you want to check whether all the target servers are pingable or not ? – [Shasha99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40907681/run-adhoc-wait-for-with-delegate-to#comment69031712_40907681)
> - Not pingable. Ssh-able.

I have no clue why you want to employ Ansible to do this. Here's a simple bash loop (add an outer one to iterate over your hosts):

```
for i in {1..30}; do
  ssh $host true 2> /dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    exit
  else
    sleep 10
  fi
done
```

Comment: i know there are ways around it. Im curious if what im suggesting is possible (combining adhoc, wait_for and delegate_to with any combination)

Answer (score 0):

[@Shasha99's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40907681/run-adhoc-wait-for-with-delegate-to#comment69030319_40907681) worked for me to verify that `wait_for` works the way I expect:

```
ansible --inventory=PATH -m wait_for -a 'host=IP port=PORT delay=10 timeout=300' 127.0.0.1
```